# Need a Regular Expression that matches a number, where a comma could precede or not and a comma could be after or not?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains HTML looking substrings. There is a particular part of the string I'm interested in and it is a `<span>` tag with `class="dsa"` and I need to match a number in the `data-level` attribute.

There could be commas, if it is a list or by itself. So let's say I want to find "2", it could be "1,2,3" or "2" or "4,2" or "2,6,8"

An example string:

```
    const str = "00001111 02000<span class='stat dsa' style='background-color: lime;' data-level='1,2,5'>auxiliary unit</span> some other text<span class='stat dsa' style='background-color: lime;' data-level='1,5'>Parker Unit</span> more text who cares <span class='stat dsa' style='background-color: lime;' data-level='2'>auxiliary unit</span> even more text <span class='stat dsa' style='background-color: lime;' data-level='5,8'>auxiliary unit</span>"
```

I want the regex to find where `data-level` has a '2' in it.  Again, there could be a '2' in where a comma precedes, or might just only be a '2' or the '2' is at the end or wherever.  I did the first part of the regex, here is what I have so far:

```
    const regex = /<span\s+[^>]*\bclass=['"][^'"]*\bstat\b[^'"]\bdsa\b[^'"]*['"][^>]*\bdata-level=['"]\b( what goes here )\b['"]*>.*?<\/span>/g
```

Comment: *Do not use Regex to parse HTML*. Use an actual HTML parser. Then this task becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you should use a parser for this. However, if you *need* to use RegEx, try this:

```
/<span[^>]*class='([^']* )*dsa[^\w]([^']* ?)*'[^>]*data-level='(\d*,)*2(,\d*)*'>/g
```

The `<span[^>]` portion avoids looking across multiple tags. Similarly for the `'[^']`, for example it won't match `data-level='some text' some-param='2'`.

Comment: This should work, but I need to modify it a bit though, since it also needs the "dsa" class, but I can work with this I think.  I say that, because other spans could have the data-level, but I'm not interested in those

Comment: Updated regex to include dsa class. This makes some assumptions: class is before data-level; will match a class including dsa that isn't separate, e.g. class='asddsa'. Just be aware of these assumptions and limitations and modify accordingly!

Comment: That almost works, but it is also matching "22" or "2341" when in this case it should only be a "2".  Of course if the level was "22" then it would need to match "22"

Comment: updated to account for this; allows digits with commas before and after, but looks for a lone 2. Also added checks for other class tags with spaces to avoid something like class='asdsa'.

Comment: Yeah, you are running in the same issues I was. So this passes if  data-level="2" or "data-level="1,2", but fails if data-level="2,3" (starts out with 2 and then a comma) and fails if number after as in data-level="2,3,4" or "1,2,3,4"

I might just be doomed.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, had the \d* and , swapped in the second portion. This will match 1,2 ; 2 ; 2,3 ; 1,2,3 ; etc. but not 1,22,3 or other variations that don't include "2"

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, was just making sure it worked with all the scenarios. It seems to be working.  I'll accept this answer. I had to finish the regex with the closing tag so I added the >.*?<\/span> part at the end, but yeah it seems to work.  Thanks.